# Can you save Parse information in NSUserDefaults? (IOS)

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform, storage, nsuserdefaults

Basically, i want to save my current Parse user's friends into NSUserDefaults. For some reason it doesn't seem to be saving correctly or it won't let me save them. Is this because the array of objects(friends) that i am returning is to intricate for NSUserDefaults to handle?

I have tried turning the array of objects into NSData and saving it that way but i still haven't yielded any good results.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use NSUserDefaults for storing this type of information. NSUserDefaults was created in order to store and retrieve "settings" type information as opposed to data.

As for your question, in order to save custom objects you need to implement these 2 methods:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

}
```

These methods will essentially tell the application how to store the objects data in a file as well as how to read it back in and create an object from it.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html

However, if you are looking to store these objects locally you should look into Parse's local caching feature. You could also use Core Data to store the objects locally but maintaining 2 instances of the objects may be ugly.

**Parse Local Caching:**

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore/iOS

Comment: Preferably you would use the local cache provided by the parse SDK or something like Core Data...

Comment: You are correct, I have updated my answer to reflect how OP can achieve saving custom objects but recommending the better solution of Parse's local data store.